# How to find the differences in two IIS websites

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, website

I have two websites, one of which is a slight fork of the originals source code.
A basic feature (the use of sessions) appears to be working differently on the forked site to the original site.

I have diff'ed the source and can see no differences in the key areas, and so I am wondering if there is some way I can diff the IIS site configurations?

Is it possible to export ALL the site settings to a text file which could be diffed or is there some other way of highlighting any differences?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In IIS 6 you could have done this by looking at the metabase file, however in IIS 7 the settings for IIS are distributed over a number of files, so you would need to look at all of these :

The primary one is the applicaitonHost.config file, located at  `%windir%\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config`, this is the global web server configuration file, where all  configuration sections are declared.

You would also want to check the machine and web config files, at
`Framework\<version>\CONFIG\machine.config` and `Framework\<version>\CONFIG\web.config`

Finally, there are the web.config files for each site.

If you compare each of these files it should give you a pretty comprehensive view of the settings for each site and their differences.

Comment: Thanks Sam. Does the web.config reflect _all_ the settings in IIS. If I change something in IIS, does the web.config get updated with those chnages?

Comment: No, the settings for IIS are split over 3 files, the applicaitonHost.config, and the global web and machine .config files, there are then site specific settings that can be set, or overridden in the per site web.config files